# What is this cable, PSU to SATA, [img]?

Tags: power-supply

This connects my PSU to my SATA HD. What is this type of cable/connector called, and where can I get more, i.e. buy one such cable not a

[image: PSU to SATA]

Edit, added picture of PSU:

[image]

Comment: This is the end which goes into the PSU, right? Because it's not a SATA power connector... In that case, I think you should add the name of your PSU to your question.

Comment: Its not really an option for me to start disconnecting things further, and I can't see any identifying label on the PSU other then the logo in the picture I added above.

Comment: Also..........this was a technical support question >.<

Comment: @NZKshatriya only partially. I asked where I could get more such cables. That is asking for recommendations of where/how to get more hardware.

Comment: @qonf  You asked primarily an identification request, with a secondary request of where to get more.   Generally asking more than one distinct question if frowned upon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connector shown is a 5-pin modular power supply connector with a single side lock, possibly for a Be Quiet! power supply. They are widely available. 
[This example](https://www.scan.co.uk/products/720mm-be-quiet!-braided-s-ata-power-cable-cs-6740-for-all-current-be-quiet!-modular-psu-4-x-sata-bla) is from Scan.co.uk.

Note that most modular power supplies that use side-locking connectors have dual side locks.

Here is a Be Quiet! modular PSU with single side-lock connectors:

[image]

Pure PC

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but 5-pin modular power supply connector doesn't really seem to be very uniquely identifying. Also I seem googeling seem to suggest that these type of cables aren't really interchangeable. Perhaps you can help me Identify the PSU from the picture I have added above.

Comment: Not by looking at the fan, no. I don't wish to be rude, but if you remove the PSU from the case, you will be able to identify it for yourself.

Comment: Me neither, but removing the PSU doesn't seem like something that should be required in such an instance. Anyway, I ended up finding out that we had a leftover cables for the PSU, so the problem solved itself.

Answer (score 0):

Some shopping websites are calling it "5-Pin to SATA Modular Power Supply Unit Cable".
I don't think there's a name for the 5-pin connector.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but 5-pin modular power unit cable doesn't really seem to be very uniquely identifying. Also I seem googeling seem to suggest that these type of cables aren't really interchangeable. Perhaps you can help me Identify the PSU manufacturer from the picture I have added above.